# Chart JS - Make chart scrollable if too much data

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I have problem with chart js. I'm handling 1000's of entries in one chart, and it is just too dense and unreadable. I want it to have a scrollbar when it exceeds a certain amount of data (or a certain distance between each point). How do I do this?

If you have any other solution for this problem without a scrollbar I would like to hear it as well.

Thanks in advance,
Yoav Strugo

Answer (score -2):

If You want to add scrollbar after a certain amount of data in Chart.js. Then you can use CSS to allow horizontal (overflow-x: scroll;) or vertical (overflow-y: scroll;) scroll.

```
<style>
.chartWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.chartWrapper > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.chartAreaWrapper {
  width: 15000px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
</style>

<div class="chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
    <canvas id="chart" height="400" width="15000"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more example you can use - http://jsfiddle.net/rbdqxfzL/140